# Redirecionamento via eventos Offline Online HTML5

Tags: javascript, android, html5, app, eventos

Como fazer para identificar se o app em HTML5 identificar e redirecionar se estiver offline ou online?

Ex: Ao abrir o app se estiver sem internet carrega um html de aviso e se online redireciona para um site.

Encontrei este código mas não sei se é possível modifica-lo desta maneira.

```js
     function updateOnlineStatus(msg) {
       var status = document.getElementById("status");
       var condition = navigator.onLine ? "ONLINE" : "OFFLINE";
       status.setAttribute("class", condition);
       var state = document.getElementById("state");
       state.innerHTML = condition;
       var log = document.getElementById("log");
       log.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Event: " + msg + "; status=" + condition + "\n"));
     }
     function loaded() {
       updateOnlineStatus("load");
       document.body.addEventListener("offline", function () {
         updateOnlineStatus("offline")
       }, false);
       document.body.addEventListener("online", function () {
         updateOnlineStatus("online")
       }, false);
     }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <style>...</style>
 </head>
 <body onload="loaded()">
   <div id="status"><p id="state"></p></div>
   <div id="log"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi desta maneira:

```js
   function updateOnlineStatus(evento) {
       var status = document.getElementById("status");
       var condition = navigator.onLine ? location.href='online.html' : location.href='offline.html' ;          
     }
     function loaded() {
       updateOnlineStatus("load");
       document.body.addEventListener("offline", function () {
         updateOnlineStatus("offline")
       }, false);
       document.body.addEventListener(function () {
         updateOnlineStatus("online")
       }, false);
     }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 
 </head>
 <body onload="loaded()">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Se existir método mais simples agradeço a colaboração.